# how to use different domain names for different processes running on same server

Tags: php, node.js, web-services, go, dns

Assume I have three different sites running. Node.js app on port 3000, Apache/PHP on port 80, and then a Go app on port 5000.

How can I have three different domain names that go to each port?

I was thinking of a basic route system on port 80 that all domains refer to, then the program looks at url and redirects to correct port. Is that recommended? Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you have the basic theory. since web access is via port 80 (or 443 for ssl), you need a reverse proxy like nginx to forward traffic to the correct port

Comment: What's your web server? Nginx makes for a nice reverse proxy.

Comment: is it all http based? So cold the client needing to talk to the Go app first connect to Apache on port 80 and then redirected to domainname.com:5000?  That can be done. Question is if your client can handle the redirect

Comment: if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST' == 'go.domain.com') { header('Location:   http://go.domain.com:5000'); exit(); 
}

Comment: Yea exactly what I had in mind. That an acceptable way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Nginx, you can very easily set up named-based reverse proxy vhosts for the apps that aren't on port 80:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name nodeapp.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name goapp.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

Comment: They won't be under sane name at all. I'm more looking for goapp.com, phpapp.com, etc (not sub domain)...or does it still work?

Comment: Still works. Server name can be anything as long as it's a valid DNS name that resolves to your IP.

Comment: Oh great. And how exactly can these different proxy_passes be all seen as port 80?

Comment: The inbound port should always be 80, that's kinda the point. (Or 443 if you're using HTTPS.) It's the `proxy_pass` port that you want to change based on the app.

Comment: Cool. Finally, where is this file processed/written on server?

Comment: The file will be named `nginx.conf` -- this text can (generally) be appended to it. Where the file is located totally depends on your particular install.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're running on port 80 is just a proxy layer, you could instead use [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/), which is itself written in Go. Your Caddyfile would like something like this:

```
nodeapp.mydomain.com {
    proxy / localhost:3000
}

goapp.mydomain.com {
    proxy / localhost:5000
}
```

If not, you could still use caddy and just move your PHP application to a different port.

I suggest caddy because its creator pushes for security everywhere (you will notice you get automatic https if your site is applicable). The configuration (done in the Caddyfile) is also usually short and very easy to understand. Caddy has a wide range of use cases and can come with plugins to do just about anything you can think up.